# Best knot (hitch) to backpack webbing

Tags: knots, backpacks

I've been tying a simple shoelace knot for this, however I'm worried it will eventually become loose and come apart all together - especially when on the outside of the backpack. I am looking for a more appropriate hitch when attaching things to my backpack webbing

I'm looking for

- Close fit (The attached item should not be swinging around)
- Secure
- Fairly quick to release

[image]

Example things to strap onto (in order, monoculars, sunglasses, camera bag)

[image]

Comment: I suggest example item(s)?  For me it would vary by the item.

Comment: Added some examples, but it's not limited to that. For example, hitching a tripod that has a few holes in it (eg handle) to this with rope would count too

Comment: That backpack webbing is not really designed for heavy items.  A common technical use is crampons or helmet. For a tripod look for a climbing pack with side lashes for like skis.

Comment: What about a quick release buckle on a piece of webbing: http://cdn3.volusion.com/tf5kb.xfex7/v/vspfiles/photos/SRBSA-2.jpg?1438778491

Comment: You say you're unhappy with the shoelace knot, but you don't say why you're unhappy with it. It meets your criteria, which are a close fit and ease of release. Could you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A combination of nylon webbing (i.e., a strap) and a plastic buckle that's both quick to cinch tight or to loosen. They're usually called Accessory Straps or Compression Straps. The strap comes in different widths so make sure it will thread through your backpack straps.

Even though they're inexpensive, you can easily make your own if you buy and cut the webbing and buckles separately. Sturdy sewing is needed to attach one end of webbing permanently to the buckle.

Comment: Some buckles do not require one side to be fixed. You can also get "connectors" that will let you attach the webbing without sewing.